# DataTables gives error when table is empty

Tags: datatables

Using Datatables 1.9.4 for a Rails 3.2.6 Application.

I am using DataTable and it is working great but I had noticed that whenever my table has no data, it will give out the following errors:

DataTables warning (table id = 'resource-index-listing-table'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0.

Can someone please help.

Comment: did u found solution for this? i am also facing same problem